# Basic For loop and function Question Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I have written a function to search for the element inside a flextable in GWT. The function is given below:

```
public void searchElement(String elementName){
String column_element;
boolean found=false;
for(int i=1;i<=stocksFlexTable.getRowCount();i++){
  column_element=stocksFlexTable.getText(i,0);

  if(column_element.equalsIgnoreCase(elementName)) {
    found = true;
    Window.alert("found");

  }

}
if(!found) {
  Window.alert("Element not found");
}}
```

The function is working fine, it is able to look for element and generate alert found. However when the element is  not there, the code saying element is not found does not run.

I checked, as soon as i put a for loop, then the last line .i.e.

```
 Window.alert("Element not found");
```

does not work

Comment: what do you mean by element is not there, are you passing elementName as null or simply not matching elementName ? I am not able to reproduce your problem, "Element not found" is working for me.

Comment: @NishikantTayade thanks for replying, i meant if the text i was searching i snot inside the table